# Pagination links when searching questions by tags don't honor your current tags

Tags: bug, tags, questions, search, tag-search

Currently if I search for questions by a tag, say [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), the links at the bottom to the next pages of search results are pointing to the unfiltered list of results:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=active&page=2&pagesize=15`

Instead, it should honor the tags I currently have filtered by, so that I can see, for example, page 2 of the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) questions.

This is the case whether I have filtered by the custom questions list (a feature I have active) or by searching in the search box within the top bar.

I get this issue on Firefox 63.0 and Chrome 70.0.3538.77 as well as Edge 41.16299.547.0. [Others have not been able to reproduce this issue](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/44461278#44461278).

I created a [second ABTester account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10597497/abtester) and it *does not* occur on that account on Firefox, Chrome, or Edge. This leads me to believe this is due to some A/B testing going on.

I've not cleared my cookies yet, but this affects my account while logged in at work, as well, so this is across multiple computers.

Comment: For me, on Chrome 70.0.3538.77 on macOS, it shows filtered pages: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=newest&page=2&pagesize=15`

Comment: @Cœur The link is set to `active` for me instead of `newest` because my questions list is set to filter by *Recent Activity* rather than *Newest*. If I change it to *Newest*, the URL at the bottom updates in kind, but still loses the tag. I **can** confirm, though, when I'm logged out, I don't have the problem. Logging back in brings the problem back up for me. I will see about deleting cookies for the site and give an update once I've done that.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this and it feels like a bug. The "next" link at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23 goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=unanswered&page=2&pagesize=50 it should be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?page=2

Comment: @Cœur Of course, I agree that A/B testing shouldn't introduce bugs. However, nearly every change the team has made in the last year (at least the ones they've written an announcement post for) has introduced unexpected/unintended bugs/regressions, so... I don't want to rule it out.

Comment: I am also able to reproduce this issue (Chrome 70.0.3538.77). I'm trying to browse the R taged questions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r and the link to page 2 at the bottom goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=newest&page=2&pagesize=15 (basically it forgets the tag). I did also opt into the "Custom Question Lists" beta.

Comment: I have this patched in my userscript [HoverExpandNavigationLinks](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/HoverExpandNavigationLinks.user.js) in the meantime.

Answer (score 5):

A repro here when opted in for [Custom Question Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/):

Using Firefox 63.0.1 on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.4

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design Filter, all ;Sort Newest.

Clicking Next redirects to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=newest&page=2&pagesize=50

Independent of my Sort this redirects with a removing of the search.

Comment: "... but don't know if I'm included." That's pretty easy to find out: Open a tag page like [tag:design] in your case. If you see the question count you're *not* in the beta.

Comment: Then I'm in the beta ;)

Answer (score 1):

(Merging contents from my other question here)

Here is what is going on:

[image]

This also applies to other tabs such as newest, active and unanswered. Issue is present in the "Custom Question Lists" feature. Does not happen with standard question lists:

[image]