# Paging broken when watching a tag?

Tags: discussion, bug

I've selected "Public questions tagged [cmd]":

[image]

Unfortunately the paging links at the bottom of the page are broken, for example the link behind <kbd>2</kbd> is `https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=newest&page=2&pagesize=50`

The link should presumably be something like `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd?page=2&sort=newest&pagesize=50`

This is working correctly on SuperUser, when the equivalent link (when watching [cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd.exe)) is `https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cmd.exe?sort=newest&page=2&pagesize=50`

This is with Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 63.0.1.

Comment: Maybe related: [Pagination links when searching questions by tags don't honor your current tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376162/2675154)

Comment: @honk Indeed. Same problem. My searching didn't find it :/